# How to determine unknown vector in a Bayesian linear model?

Tags: linear-algebra, bayesian, estimation

In (Kay 1993, pg. 326), a theorem is stated, which allows to find the weight parameters of a linear model

$$
  \bf{x} = \bf{G}\bf{\eta} + \bf{w}
$$

where $\bf{\eta} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_\eta, \bf{C}_\eta)$ and $\bf{w} \sim \mathcal{N}(\bf{0},\bf{C}_w)$.

As far as I understand, all the vectors in $\bf{G}$ are deterministic and known. Let's say $\bf{G} = [\bf{s}~\bf{H}]$, where $\bf{H}$ is known and $\bf{s}$ a *deterministic but unknown* vector. Is there a way that I can estimate it? We can assume that $\bf{s}$ is orthogonal to $\bf{H}$. Also, consider $\eta = [\alpha~\theta^{T}]^{T}$, where $\alpha$ is a scalar.

**Note 1**: *Origin of the problem*
I have a dataset of observations $\bf{X} = [\bf{X}_c~\bf{X}_n]$ where I know the following

\begin{equation}
  \forall \bf{x} \in \bf{X_c},\, \bf{x}=\alpha\bf{s} + \bf{w}\\
  \forall \bf{x} \in \bf{X_n},\, \bf{x}=\alpha\bf{s} + \bf{H}\theta + \bf{w}
\end{equation}

Note that $\alpha$ and $\bf{s}$ are unknown. I know the first line is just a particular case of the second, where $\theta=\bf{0}$. So, my thought is that I could do away with having two models and just unify them. My initial thought was to consider the weights as random and use a Bayesian approach. I can identify a somewhat similar model to (Kay 1993) if I consider $\eta = [\alpha~\theta^{T}]^{T}$ and that kind of settles the estimation of $\alpha$. I can also consider $\bf{G} = [\bf{s}~\bf{H}]$, but since $\bf{s}$ is unknown, I'll need to estimate that.

**Note 2**: *MVU estimator of weights*
A closed-form minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\eta$ is

$$
  \hat{\eta}_{\text{MVU}} = (\bf{G}^T \bf{C}_w^{-1} \bf{G} )^{-1}\bf{G}^{T}\bf{C}_w^{-1} \bf{x}
$$

with $\bf{C}_w$ the noise covariance. This is the direct consequence of applying Theorem 10.3 in (Kay 1993) and assuming that the prior for $\eta$ is non-informative. I was thinking maybe to iteratively estimate $\bf{s}$ by alternation i.e. estimate $\eta$ first, then $\bf{s}$, and repeat.

Comment: How do you introduce $\bf{s}$? And it seems to me that you want to introduce also an $\alpha$. So, your model is 
$$ \bf{x} = \bf{G}\bf{\eta} + \bf{w}+\alpha \bf{s}$$
and you want to estimate $\alpha$, $\bf{s}$ and $\mu_{\eta}$ with $\bf{G}, \bf{C}_\eta$ and $\bf{C}_w$ are given, don't you?

Comment: @NN2 I edited the question. I made a mistake: I want to find $\bf{s}$, which is a column in $\bf{G}$ that is deterministic but unknown, and not to add an extra vector.